# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService Authorization failed. These requirements were not met: Requires an authenticated user

Tags: c#, blazor

When I deploy a NET 6 blazor web app (server and client) into IIS but I got this error when I run it, http://blazorecommerceapi.findingsteve.net

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

[image]

When I run its api, http://blazorecommerceapi.findingsteve.net/api/product

[image]

But when I run it locally, it works as expected. I can run the blazor client page.

[image]

I can see the api data.

[image]

I am using Sqlite to persist the data and for the authentication, these are some codes in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey =
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                .GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Error 500 is often from code errors, use try catch and write logs to check?

Comment: I'm also getting this error @Steve, did you find a solution?

Comment: I am getting the same error, any luck?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one here. I just don't see how adding SQLite to the project breaks Authentication... the mind boggles.

Comment: I'm struggling with this aswell i have no backend storage for users, i just return a token, but even if i dont send a token at all i still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Checking `FallbackPolicy` configuration and set arguments for `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` something like this:

```
config.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
          .Build();
```